# Python Autologin impossible to compile

Tags: python, selenium, compilation, autologin

I wanted to try autologin with Python but I get this error when I´m compiling:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thega\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\thega\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\thega\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/thega/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/thega/Downloads/chromedriverwin64/')
  File "C:\Users\thega\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\thega\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I´m using this code from Internet(it should work fine):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


username = 'name'
password = 'passwd'

url = 'https://www.page.net/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/thega/Downloads/chromedriverwin64/')

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id('inputUsername').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id('inputPassword').send_keys(password)

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_id('loginButton').click()
```

PS: I´m new to Python.
PS2: I´m using PyCharm if that helps.
And yes, I have **already installed selenium**.

Thanks for any help.